# Matching IC drive capacitance with MOSFET input capacitance?

Tags: mosfet, driver, capacitance

A quick and simple question:

> If I have a microcontroller pin that says that it "is designed to drive capacitive loads of up to 70 pF", does that mean that I can directly drive MOSFETs from the pin that have an input capacitance of 70 pF or less?

Obviously we are talking about low current logic level MOSFETs so that this is even remotely feasible, for example [2N7002K](http://www.vishay.com/docs/71333/2n7002k.pdf). Also it is obvious that the microcontroller can switch higher capacitance MOSFETs, just takes longer to do it, as long as current is limited so that the microcontroller is not damaged.

The key words here would be "designed" and "recommended operation". Under what circumstances would you recommend connecting a MOSFET to a microcontroller without a gate driver in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When

- the voltage produced by the uC is sufficient
- the switching time (resulting from the - limited - drive capability, maybe further limited by a series resistor,  and the effective (!) gate capacitance) is acceptable
- there is no danger of 'backdrive' from the switching in the mosfet back to the gate to the uC (this can be a reason to include a gate series resistor)

When you are switching a 20mA LED or a 100mA relais using a TO92 logic-level mosfet I would drive the gate directly without hesitation (but I would check whether the gate voltage is sufficient) . When PWMming 10A motor I would not dream of doing so. In between there is of course a gray area, where careful consideration (and some smoking experiments) might save you a mosfet driver chip.

(edit - add "using a TXB0108 as fast mosfet driver")

The TXB0108 is a wonderful chip, but it drives its outputs in a very special way: a short pulse of relatively low impedance (50..100 ohm), then sustained by a relatively high impedance (4k). I could not find the duration of the pulse in the datasheet.

Your mosfet must have an low enough effective gate capacitance that it is sufficiently charged by the pulse. As ballpark value you could use the 70pF mentioned in the TXB0108 datahseet (minus PC stray capacitance, etc.).

The switching delays of the  TXB0108 are up to ~ 10 ns with 15 pF load. This does not make me feel comfortable about reaching 100 ns with 70 pF.

The allowed voltage on a TXB0108 pin is 0.5 .. 6.5 V: there is margin beyond the supply range, with clamp currents of 50 mA. That might well mean that the chip is reasonably protected from latch-up and other unwanted effects that could be caused by backdriving. But note that this is in the infamous 'absolute maxima' section, NOT in the normal operations.

Management summary: the TXB0108 datasheet does not provide sufficient details, ballpark spec for the mosfet is < 50 pF effective gate capacitance, 100 ns might be achievable, but experiments will be needed to verify the design. Backdriving might not be a problem (specs look much better than an average uC pin), so the series resistor might not be needed, but again: insufficient data.

Comment: Nice answer in general - however, that does not help me actually evaluate the drive capability against the effective gate capacitance, which was specifically my question.

Comment: If you want to evaluate a specific situation, you must provide the specifics. Which uC, at which voltage, which mosfet, which current, and how long switching time is acceptable?

Comment: I did not want a direct answer to a specific situation, I wanted an explanation on how to evaluate the parameters myself so I can come up with the asnwer - that is, I wanted to learn. However, to get to concrete terms, let's say that the chip is TXB0108 and I would need to pick a MOSFET to switch 1A, 5V current. Switching time should be shortish, say <100ns. What requirements do I have for the MOSFET?

Comment: Very nice answer now! I had no idea the answer could be "insufficient data", but you really made the point clearly. What the take away point from this for me is that the choices are too hard to verify here and it is better to use either a gate driver in between, or just an analog switch if one wants design that will not be broken when the microcontrolles is substituted for something else.